# Find out whether a function has a removable singularity at $z_0 = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z) = \frac{ \cos(z-1)}{z^2} $. $z_0 = 0$

Isn't $f(z)$ already in laurent expansin at $z_0=0$ and so it wouldnt have a removable singularity at $0$ since $b_1=1$?

Or, do we have to use $\cos(z-1) = \cos(1) \cos z + \sin(1) \sin z $ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\lim_{z \to 0} \cos(z - 1) = \cos(-1) \neq 0$, you have $\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{\cos(z-1)}{z^2} = +\infty$ and so $z_0 = 0$ can't be a removable singularity. As written, $f$ is given as a Laurent series $\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} a_n z^n$ - you can find the expansion of $f$ by finding the Taylor expansion of $\cos(z - 1)$ around $z_0 = 0$ and dividing by $z^2$ but this is not necessary to deduce whether $z_0 = 0$ is a removable singularity or not.